# Arranging plots horizontally first rather than vertically: marrangeGrob in r

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a list of plots (ggplot2 objects) that I'm arranging across multiple pages within a R Markdown document that is eventually knitted as a PDF document. I'm using the marrangeGrob() function from gridExtra to do this. My issue can actually be illustrated using the example provided on the gridExtra vignettes page (link below). You can see that the plots are arranged vertically first, rather than horizontally. I would like to do the opposite (i.e, go plot 1 + 2 on the top of the example, and 3 + 4 on the bottom, rather than 1+3 on the top, and 2+4 on the bottom).

Thoughts? 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html

Example code taken directly from this page (full attribution to the author!).

I've tried setting as.table = TRUE as well as tried to set the matrix layout as options within the marrangeGrob() call without success. I've also tried calling individual parts of the list and manually setting through layout, but the layout isn't as neat (or as simple in terms of code) as doing everything within the marrangeGrob() function. I'm also not keen on changing the order of objects within my list unless this is the only option.

R Studio Version 1.1.463;
R version 3.5.3

Thank you!

```r
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)

set.seed(123)
pl <- lapply(1:11, function(.x) 
             qplot(1:10, rnorm(10), main=paste("plot", .x)))
ml <- marrangeGrob(pl, ncol=2, nrow=2, as.table = FALSE)
ml
```

Comment: try adding `layout_matrix = matrix(1:4, 2, 2, TRUE)`

Comment: Perfect! This works wonderfully. Thank you for your help!